# Rejoining two partitions

Tags: partitioning

I was curious about Ubuntu and decided that I would dual-boot it and Windows.  After finding that I hadn't used Windows since, I deleted my Windows partition with GParted.  Now, I want to use this freed disk space with Ubuntu.  How can I merge this disk space with the Ubuntu partition?

Answer (score 1):

While on live-cd run GParted. Then right click on partition You want to resize and set right amount of space.

Comment: Ah, ok, but I installed it from usb (wich is now formated). Do I have to download and mount a usb again and go into live-cd?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Live CD and gparted pre-installed to do this.

You 1st need to delete the formatted (empty) partition and then use gparted to resize the existing Linux partition and grow it (ext4 is fine).

To get a USB live, the easiest thing would be using `unetbootin` http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ to create a Live USB from ISO or Internet.

BTW: I would avoid resizing existing Linux partitions, unless you are using LVM or Btrfs. In this case, I would rather use the empty partition as `/home`, copy the data from old home to new and modify `/etc/fstab`, after that you can delete the old home on the Linux partition to free up disk space.

To copy data from old home to new (if you use a Live USB, mount old / as /mnt/root and new /home as /mnt/new_home)

```
rsync -axHAX --progress /mnt/root/home/user /mnt/new_home
```

Answer (score 0):

Start up an Ubuntu LiveCD or USB.  Then, use GParted to "resize" the partition you created for Ubuntu until it fills the whole disk.  This may take a long time, depending on the size of your disk.

This can only be done from live media - you will have to make another LiveUSB.  To do this, Ubuntu provides a built-in tool called "Startup Disk Creator", but you can also use a tool such as UNetBootin, PenDriveLinux, etc.

Good luck with Ubuntu!